# What is the economic sense in multiplying standard deviation by the root of the sample size?

Tags: stock-market

I found an example when a so-called `volatility index` is calculated by multiplication of a `sample standard deviation` by the `square root of the sample size`, see [here](https://www.bitmex.com/app/index/.BVOL24H)

Does it make a good sense, and why? If it does, why not `SQRT(N-1)`?

Comment: The question is whether you want standard deviation of changes per observation or standard deviation per day (assuming independence)